# Show MySQL tables starting with prefix?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get MySQL tables by name starting with prefix `"someprefix_"`, but I get wrong (?) results.
I tried to execute `SHOW COLUMNS LIKE 'someprefix_%'` but problem is, that I have also tables with prefix `"someprefix2_"` and those tables are also being returned in the result.

Is there a way to exclude tables with a similar prefix from the result?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To list all tables with some prefix, "any number of symbols" wildcard (`%`), should be used.

`_` is also a wildcard, representing any single symbol, and therefore it should be escaped.

Therefore, given your prefix is `someprefix_`, then

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'someprefix\_%'
```

would work

Comment: it shows the table names but i can not view the table data as they are not clickable

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW [FULL] TABLES [{FROM | IN} db_name]
[LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]
```